# Push Notification not functionning

Tags: android, push-notification

I have followed all the steps in order to include Push Notifications in my app, without success.

I added the following code to my Manifest file:

```
<service android:name=".util.MyAndroidFirebaseMsgService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
<!-- [END firebase_service] -->
<!-- [START firebase_iid_service] -->
<service android:name=".util.MyAndroidFirebaseInstanceIdService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

I copied the Json file that was generated by the firebase console.

I created my 2 classes:

```
public class MyAndroidFirebaseMsgService extends FirebaseMessagingService 
public class MyAndroidFirebaseInstanceIdService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService
```

I overrode the 2 functions in each one respectively: onMessageReceived, onTokenRefresh.

Finally, I updated the gradle files:

Project Level:

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
```

App Level

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.6.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.2'
```

I am trying to send a notification test from my firebase console without success. Nothing is received.

Best Regards.

Comment: Have you tried sending a notification to a single device? You can do it from the console using the token given at the `onTokenRefresh()` inside the `MyAndroidFirebaseInstanceIdService`.

Comment: I haven't even received the Token :(

Comment: In that function use `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();` and put a breakpoint or a Log to read it

Comment: already done. i am not getting there.
Having this error in my Logcat:

Comment: 11-29 10:37:56.579 9011-18596/? E/Auth: [GoogleAccountDataServiceImpl] getToken() -> BAD_AUTHENTICATION. Account: <ELLIDED:-818113082>, App: com.google.android.gms, Service: oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userlocation.reporting
                                        efm: Long live credential not available.
efn.b(:com.google.android.gms@11746448:10)
android.content.AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter$SyncThread.run(AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter.java:272)
11-29 10:37:56.579 9011-18596/? W/Auth: [GetToken] GetToken failed with status code: BadAuthentication

Comment: Maybe you have the wrong credentials for Firebase. Try downloading a new `google-services.json` from your Firebase project and put it in your Android project. Then check if you can get the token.